# Equivalent R's arima function in Python

Tags: python, r, time-series, statsmodels, arima

I tried a time series forecast with Python using statsmodel's arima function and it gave me a different result from the r's arima function.
I used the same hyper-parameters.

R's version :

```
fit <- arima(data[1:9000,3], order = c(3,0,3), seasonal = list(order = c(0,0,0)))
predd = forecast(fit,h=1000)
pred = cbind(data[9001:10000,3], predd$mean)
```

Python's version :

```
series = df[0:9000].copy()
model = ARIMA(series, order=(3, 0, 3))
model_fitted = model.fit()
predictions = model_fitted.predict(start=len(series), end=len(df)-1)
```

Attached are the plots results [Plots of the R's and Python's arima](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umS3Z.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Is there any other Python package/function arima that I can use other than statsmodel for a univariate time series?

Any insight or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Hard to know what's going on without an example that we can replicate. To me, it looks like the graph you're showing from R contains in-sample predictions, while the graph you're showing from Statsmodels contains out-of-sample forecasts.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. In fact, based on this (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/260899/what-is-difference-between-in-sample-and-out-of-sample-forecasts) link, both of them are out-of-sample predictions (len(df)=10000, the data of the train set(9000 values) are used to fit the model and then I make a forecast of the left 1000 values to test the model). Should I post the data and/or the whole code?

Comment: Based on the code you have already given, it looks like if you could share the data, then that would be enough to check what's going on.

Comment: Perfect, the data is available [here](https://gist.github.com/DouddaS/5043a340ff7d7b35b255b4f8f74fc534). Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Summary**: I do not know how you created the first image you showed as "R's version", but when I run the R code you gave and plot the results, they look identical to the Python results to me and do not look like the "R's version" graph you included. My best guess is that somehow you were plotting in-sample predictions when you created that image showing R's results.

See below for details.

**Details**:

I started by downloading the dataset "dataset.txt" from the link you gave, https://gist.github.com/DouddaS/5043a340ff7d7b35b255b4f8f74fc534

Now, if I run the following R code:

```
library(forecast)
y <- read.csv('dataset.txt')
fit <- arima(y[1:9000, 1], order = c(3,0,3), seasonal = list(order = c(0,0,0)))
predd = forecast(fit,h=1000)
pred = cbind(y[9001:10000,1], predd$mean)
autoplot(pred)
```

This gives the following plot:

[image: R predictions]

And when I run the following Python code:

```
y = pd.read_csv('dataset.txt')
model = sm.tsa.arima.ARIMA(y.iloc[:9000, 0], order=(3, 0, 3))
model_fitted = model.fit()
pred = model_fitted.predict(start=len(series), end=len(y)-1)
predd = pd.concat([y.iloc[9000:, 0], pred], axis=1)
predd.plot()
```

Then I get the following plot:

[image]

These look basically identical to me, and R's version looks nothing like the image that was posted in the question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response and for all the effort done. It seems that in the matplot statement used in the original code, a wrong column was taken and made this plot that I was asked to reproduce. Thank you very much!